# Set up HADOOP_HOME variable in windows

Tags: windows, hadoop

I am trying to use Spark along with Hadoop in my Windows 8. However no matter what my code is, I receive this error:

```
15/08/25 19:29:58 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:621)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2162)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2162)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
    at py4j.GatewayConnectionun(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As you can see:

```
null\bin\winutils.exe
```

The hadoop home path is null. I tried to set `HADOOP_HOME` as an environment variable but that did not resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to resolve this problem using the following part of code in the begining:

```
import sys
import os

os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "C:/Mine/Spark/hadoop-2.6.0"
sys.path.append("C:/Mine/Spark/hadoop-2.6.0/bin")
```

Hope this helps someone and also if anyone has a better idea, I would definitely appreciate that.